# SQL joining multiple tables on single column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Can I use the `USING` clause to join more than 2 tables? i.e. can I do this

```
SELECT * FROM (a, b, c) USING(date)
```

or something similar instead of

```
SELECT * FROM a, b USING(date), c USING(date)
```

?

I am using MySQL.

**EDIT**
I see from the answers that I am misunderstood. The second example works fine, but just gets very long and verbose for many tables. I am looking for a cleaner syntax, not even more complicated ways to achieve this.

Comment: WHY whats the alogorithim or problem you want to solve or achive

Comment: @shareef I am joining 10+ tables (NOT a good idea, but I don't have a choice here), all on the date column, and just wanted a cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such syntax to achieve what you want, however there is one thing that comes close:

It's kind of looked down upon, but you could look into using is the `NATURAL JOIN` syntax, where the condition(s) used for the join are implicit in that you don't need to specify the columns to join on. The implicit condition happens on columns that have the same name across the tables you're joining.

If `date` is the only column that has the same name across all of your tables, then you could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
NATURAL JOIN b
NATURAL JOIN c
```

This will implicitly join the tables on the column `date` because the field name is the same in the tables.

The downside of this approach is of course the fact that you can't have any other columns with the same name in another table or else your joins will break as those columns will *also* be factored into the join condition unintentionally.

More on [`NATURAL JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join)

Comment: The big downside of `NATURAL JOIN`s is that they join on *any* common name (&& common format columns).

Comment: This is the only answer so far that actually answers the question, though it doesn't help me since there are other columns with the same name.

Comment: @baruch Unfortunately the syntax you want to use is ambiguous. Try and understand where the ambiguities might come from, why the most used syntaxes are more complex and why they allow you more control over what you are doing, and you'll end up feeling more comfortable with them.

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately you can't use the syntax in your example. It's not valid SQL.

Instead you could use any of the following:

You can use the explicit `JOIN` syntax to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT *
    FROM x
    LEFT JOIN y USING(date)
    LEFT JOIN z USING(date);
```

Usually for better control you'd use the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT *
    FROM x
    LEFT JOIN y ON x.date = y.date
    LEFT JOIN z ON y.date = z.date;
```

Comment: This does not achieve what I want. I want to write the using clause only once for a whole list of tables that are all joined on the same column.

Comment: Also, your 2 examples aren't equivalent. The `ON` example will have 2 date columns, while the `USING` one will only have 1.

Comment: @baruch Your question was "can this be done". Instead of answering "no that isn't proper SQL syntax" I answered "this is the proper SQL syntax". I'll update my answer to mention the fact that your examples aren't proper SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION ALL

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE myDate = 'yourDate'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM b WHERE myDate = 'yourDate'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM c WHERE myDate = 'yourDate'
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is what the original poster wanted.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JOIN clause to join two tables, but the two tables must be connected with foreign key, for example:

```
SELECT Persons.Name
FROM Persons
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Persons.Id = Orders.Id;
```

Comment: -1 for fhe mention of the word **must** instead of mentioning **should**. MyISAM for example doesn't support/enforce foreign key constraints.